# How to insert matrix columns into matching list columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, matrix, nested

I have code that uses a list to store values in an organized manner, and a matrix function that performs difficult calculations. I would like to inject the matrix columns into the correct section of the corresponding list. The column names differ between the list and the matrix (due to the ability to nest within lists and assign names at the different levels which is very handy and important for managing complex datasets), but they have commonalities. How can I systematically inject the matrix columns into the correct section of the list, by matching those common identifiers, as shown in the image below? In the fuller code this example is derived from, the list, and the equivalent of `mat1` are dynamic: thus, I am looking for a systematic manner to do this.

In the below example, common identifiers are "Series", "Class", and "P_advance".

Code for generating the example function and matrix are at the bottom of this post.

[image]

Below is code for the `classPrin()` function and for generating matrix `mat1`:

```
seriesList <- list(
  Series_One = data.frame(
    Class = c('Class_A','Class_B','Class_C'),
    ClassPct = c(0.5,0.2,0.06)
  ),
  Series_Two = data.frame(
    Class = c('Class_A','Class_B'),
    ClassPct = c(0.7,0.3)
  )
)

classPrin <- function(periods) {
  series_names <- c("Series_One","Series_Two")
  bucket <- list()
  
  for (series in series_names) {
    series_elements <- seriesList[[series]][["Class"]]
    bucket[[series]] <- list()
  
    for (element in series_elements) {
      mat <- matrix(0, nrow = periods, 2)
      colnames(mat) <- c(
        'P_advance',
        'FC_cover_CO'
      )
      mat[,"P_advance"] <- 0
      bucket[[series]][[element]] <- mat
    } 
  } 
  return(bucket)
}

mat1 <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
colnames(mat1) <- c(
  "Series_One_Class_A_P_advance",
  "Series_One_Class_B_P_advance",
  "Series_Two_Class_A_P_advance"
)
mat1[,1] <- 1:5
mat1[,2] <- 11:15
mat1[,3] <- 21:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, although I wonder if my for-loop approach is juvenile. I figured this is a common problem and that there must be a slick R way to do this. Maybe not. As a relative newcomer to R (I don't know for how long I can hold on to that excuse) my first impulse is to attack with a for-loop. But the below works.

```
classPrin5 <- classPrin(5)

# Function to insert values from mat1 into object generated by classPrin()
insertValues <- function(classPrinList, mat, prefix) {
  for (series_name in names(classPrinList)) {
    for (class_name in names(classPrinList[[series_name]])) {
      col_name <- paste(series_name, class_name, "P_advance", sep = "_")
      if (col_name %in% colnames(mat)) {
        values_to_insert <- mat[, col_name]
        classPrinList[[series_name]][[class_name]][,"P_advance"] <- values_to_insert
      }
    }
  }
  return(classPrinList)
}

# Run the function
insertValues(classPrin5, mat1)
```

Which gives the following correct output:

```
> insertValues(classPrin5, mat1)
$Series_One
$Series_One$Class_A
     P_advance FC_cover_CO
[1,]         1           0
[2,]         2           0
[3,]         3           0
[4,]         4           0
[5,]         5           0

$Series_One$Class_B
     P_advance FC_cover_CO
[1,]        11           0
[2,]        12           0
[3,]        13           0
[4,]        14           0
[5,]        15           0

$Series_One$Class_C
     P_advance FC_cover_CO
[1,]         0           0
[2,]         0           0
[3,]         0           0
[4,]         0           0
[5,]         0           0


$Series_Two
$Series_Two$Class_A
     P_advance FC_cover_CO
[1,]        21           0
[2,]        22           0
[3,]        23           0
[4,]        24           0
[5,]        25           0

$Series_Two$Class_B
     P_advance FC_cover_CO
[1,]         0           0
[2,]         0           0
[3,]         0           0
[4,]         0           0
[5,]         0           0
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a for loop. In fact, it will probably much faster than what I suggested. Although, I'd make some small adjustments to make it less dependent on hard-coded values. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents:

```
## Inputs
classPrin(5) -> classPrin5 # function taken from the question

matrix(c(1:5, 11:15, 21:25), 5 , 3, FALSE,
      list(NULL, c("Series_One_Class_A_P_advance",
                   "Series_One_Class_B_P_advance",
                   "Series_Two_Class_A_P_advance"))) -> mat1

## Packages (R version 4.2.2)
library(dplyr)  # dplyr_1.1.2
library(tidyr)  # tidyr_1.3.0
library(tibble) # tibble_3.2.1
library(purrr)  # purrr_1.0.1
```

```
## Pre-Processing
map(classPrin5, ~map(.x, data.frame)) %>%
  map(., ~bind_rows(.x, .id = "Class")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "Series") %>% 
  group_by(Series, Class) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()-> flat_classPrin5

mat1 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  gather(var, val, everything()) %>% 
  transmute(scp = strsplit(var,  "(?:[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){1})\\K_", perl = T), val) %>% 
  unnest_wider("scp", names_sep = "_") %>% 
  setNames(c("Series", "Class", "Par", "Val")) %>%
  group_by(Series, Class) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols =  c(Series, Class, rn), 
              names_from = "Par", values_from = "Val") -> pr_mat1
```

```
## Final output
flat_classPrin5 %>% 
  full_join(., pr_mat1, by = c("Series", "Class", "rn"), suffix = c(".l", ".m")) %>% 
  transmute(Series, Class, 
            P_advance = coalesce(P_advance.m, P_advance.l), FC_cover_CO) %>% 
  split(., .$Series, drop = T) %>% 
  map(., ~split(.x, .x$Class, drop =T))
```

```
#> $Series_One
#> $Series_One$Class_A
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Series     Class   P_advance FC_cover_CO
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Series_One Class_A         1           0
#> 2 Series_One Class_A         2           0
#> 3 Series_One Class_A         3           0
#> 4 Series_One Class_A         4           0
#> 5 Series_One Class_A         5           0
#> 
#> $Series_One$Class_B
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Series     Class   P_advance FC_cover_CO
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Series_One Class_B        11           0
#> 2 Series_One Class_B        12           0
#> 3 Series_One Class_B        13           0
#> 4 Series_One Class_B        14           0
#> 5 Series_One Class_B        15           0
#> 
#> $Series_One$Class_C
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Series     Class   P_advance FC_cover_CO
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Series_One Class_C         0           0
#> 2 Series_One Class_C         0           0
#> 3 Series_One Class_C         0           0
#> 4 Series_One Class_C         0           0
#> 5 Series_One Class_C         0           0
#> 
#> 
#> $Series_Two
#> $Series_Two$Class_A
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Series     Class   P_advance FC_cover_CO
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Series_Two Class_A        21           0
#> 2 Series_Two Class_A        22           0
#> 3 Series_Two Class_A        23           0
#> 4 Series_Two Class_A        24           0
#> 5 Series_Two Class_A        25           0
#> 
#> $Series_Two$Class_B
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Series     Class   P_advance FC_cover_CO
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Series_Two Class_B         0           0
#> 2 Series_Two Class_B         0           0
#> 3 Series_Two Class_B         0           0
#> 4 Series_Two Class_B         0           0
#> 5 Series_Two Class_B         0           0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>